# request.getParameter() showing null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following FORM in JSP

```
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <input type="number" name="minPrice" id="minPrice" title="Minimum Price" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Minimum Price"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" title="Maximum Price" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Maximum Price"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" title="Company" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Company"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>
</form>
```

And the `doPost()` method in my servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Float minPrice , maxPrice;
    try {
        minPrice = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("minPrice"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        minPrice = null;
    }

    try {
        maxPrice = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("maxPrice"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        maxPrice = null;
    }

    String company;
    try {
        company = request.getParameter(request.getParameter("company"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        company = null;
    }
    System.out.println(minPrice + " " + maxPrice + " " + company);

    Connection conn = MyUtils.getStoredConnection(request);

    String errorString = null;
    List<Car> list = null;
    try {
        list = DBUtils.getCars(conn);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorString = e.getMessage();
    }

    if (minPrice != null && maxPrice != null) {
        if (maxPrice < minPrice) {
            errorString = "";
        }
    }

    if (list != null) {
        System.out.println(list.size());

        Iterator<Car> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Car car = iter.next();

            if (minPrice != null) {
                //System.out.println("Min is not null");
                if (car.getCostPerDay() < minPrice) {
                    iter.remove();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (maxPrice != null) {
                //System.out.println("Max is not null");
                if (car.getCostPerDay() > maxPrice) {
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
            if (company != null) {
                if (!car.getCompany().equalsIgnoreCase(company))
                    iter.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }

    request.setAttribute("errorString", errorString);
    request.setAttribute("productList", list);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/carListView.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

When I input either the minPrice or maxPrice or both, I can see the output, as in the System.out.println() message, like this:

When maxPrice is 10000:
`null 10000.0 null`

When minPrice is 4000:
`4000.0 null null`

When company is Maruti Suzuki:
`null null null`

I have set the name attribute of the company in the FORM, so that it can be accessed via Servlet, just like how I did for minPrice and maxPrice, still, I'm not able to get its value inside the servlet. I don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: set the name of the servlet as the action of the form in the jsp file

Comment: I think Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("maxPrice")) throwing exception and you maxPrice and  minPrice  set to null in catch block. Can you verify it.

Comment: It indeed is. / refers to the servlet URL Pattern

Comment: @RaheelaAslam no. As I said, I am able to retrieve value of minPrice and maxPrice, both separately and together, using the System.out.println(), but not company

Comment: ok @Sparker0i why you are getting company parameter as request.getParameter(request.getParameter("company")); while for minPrice and maxPrice not getting like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you doing a `getParameter` of a `getParameter` as in

```
request.getParameter(request.getParameter("company"));
```

change to

```
company = request.getParameter("company");
```

**Also** I suggest that you do not simply swallow your exceptions